# How to restore version control in XCode?

Tags: xcode, macos, git, xcode4.5

I have just recently backed-up my XCode C++ project on my pendrive, using

```
rsync -avu
```

Since then, the version control for my project is grayed-out on every files, I can modify the files and not see the "M" nor the "A" sign. The only files still having version-control working "shared" files for which it works correctly. (Those shared files belong to a different project called "Shared").

I have tried `git commit -m`, `git add .` and even `git init` where the files were. Nothing worked.

Can you please help restoring version control for my project?

---

UPDATE:

Answers for the questions in commens (and answers):

1. my git repository is on my local hard drive.
2. I went to the Organiser-repository pane in XCode and I see my recent `git commit -m "sth"` as "sth" az a commit. I have a single branch: master.
3. Im not sure what command would be good to test git, as my commits work (theoretically).
4. I have a folder named `.git` in the project folder.
5. `git log` is working, showing the same as XCode Organiser-repository pane.

I think the XCode just can't synchronise with the git for some reason, and I don't know how to correct that.

Comment: is your git repository "local" or on some remote server?  Do you see anything useful listed when you go to Xcode Organizer's "Repositories" pane?

Comment: Are you still able to use git from the command line? It's a useful test to see whether the problem is with Xcode or your repository.

Comment: Thanks for the questions, I've updated the question with the answers.

Answer (score 1):

First off, this is not an answer that will fix your problem, I just try to provide some help that might get you closer to a diagnosis.

Git stores its files in a folder named `.git`. Check if this folder is present in your project. If it's not then your Git repository is gone.

Next, try some basic command such as `git log`. For this to work, you must first `cd` to your project folder (or a subfolder thereof), because whenever you run a Git command it will look for the `.git` folder in the cwd or a parent folder. If `git log` does not work then your Git repository is broken in some way. Someone else will have to step in to further diagnose the problem, as I am no expert on this subject.

Finally, you should also check whether your `rsync` command has really sync'ed your project's `.git` folder with the backup's `.git` folder. Use this command:

```
diff -rq /path/to/project/.git /path/to/backup/.git
```

If there is no difference (as I would expect if `rsync` has worked correctly) then the problem with your Git repository is both in your project and in your backup. If there *are* differences then it might be worthwile to try your next steps on a *copy* of the backup (it should be fine to make the copy in the Finder).

Good luck.